# Как проверить файл на соответствие кодировке UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Есть файлы. Задача проверить соответствуют ли они кодировке UTF-8 (все символы должны быть в этой кодировке).

Проверять визуально в каком-либо редакторе не предлагать, так как файлы могут быть достаточно большими - 500МБ или даже более 1ГБ.

P.S. Эти файлы - товарные фиды формата csv. С некоторыми из них проблемы при импорте в БД MySQL командой LOAD DATA FILE... MySQL при этом ругается "Invalid utf8 character string: '...".

Поэтому дополнительно отдельно хочу проверить их на соответствие кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: Смотрите правила кодирования UTF-8, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 На любом языке пишите функцию проверки. Вот например на js https://github.com/wayfind/is-utf8/blob/master/is-utf8.js

Comment: Прогоните через `iconv -f utf-8 -t UCS-4 YOUR-FILE >/dev/null`.